# Почему, когда я ввожу, например, 1994, выдает 28 года?

Tags: javascript

Первая строчка else if как будто игнорируется, выводит неверную подпись для возраста. Например, 28 года и тд
Что в моем коде сделано неправильно?

```
let la = prompt('Ваше имя');
let lo = +prompt('Ваш год рождения');

let agge = 2022 - lo

if (agge % 10 == 1) {
    alert(`${la} : ${agge} год`)
} else if (agge % 10 == 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || 0) {
    alert(`${la} : ${agge} лет`)
} else if (agge % 10 == 2 || 3 || 4) {
    alert(`${la} : ${agge} года`)
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%5Bjavascript%5D

Comment: В какой книге вы прочитали вот это : `== 5 || 6 || 7 || 8 || 9 || 0` ?